# Capture the correct option data in selectbox angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a selectbox with options that comes from my backend :

```
  $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/abb/getDataOptionsForAbb/' + $rootScope.abbForm)
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.abbOptions = response.data;
                //console.log($scope.abbOptions);

        });

$scope.onChangeSuperCustomer = function() {
            console.log($scope.selectedSupercustomer);
        }
```

I'm using ng-options :

```
<td><select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item.superkund_id as item.namn for item in abbOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer()" ><option value=''>Select</option></select></td>
```

The output from my console.log($scope.selectedSupercustomer) is wrong. It is not the value I chose in my selectbox.

Comment: @Anant: I don't know how to use jsfiddle :/

Comment: your code should work.. In any case could you reproduce problem with plunkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td><select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item.superkund_id as item.namn for item in abbOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer(selectedSupercustomer)" ><option value=''>Select</option></select></td>
```

OR:

```
<td><select class="form-control input-sm2" ng-model="selectedSupercustomer" ng-options="item.superkund_id as item.namn for item in abbOptions" ng-change="onChangeSuperCustomer()" >    <option value=''>Select</option></select></td>
```

Js:

```
$scope.onChangeSuperCustomer = function(selectedSupercustomer) {
        console.log(selectedSupercustomer);
    }
```

**OR:**

```
   $scope.onChangeSuperCustomer = function() {
        console.log($scope.selectedSupercustomer);
    }
```

Comment: using `$scope.selectedSupercustomer` inside controller function should also work, why you are passing scope value as function parameter